# Is it possible to prevent Ubuntu Server booting into emergency mode?

Tags: 18.04, server

I have a backup harddrive connected to my Ubuntu server via USB. Every time there is a power loss and the UPS does not hold long enough, the USB drive unmounts forcefully and it causes the entire Ubuntu Server to boot into "Emergency mode".

The problem is that there is no networking therefore no SSH in emergency mode and it's impossible to fix the server remotely. The server is fine except for the USB drive and therefore IMO it should boot just fine.

Can I disable the emergency mode somehow?

Comment: Emergency mode might save you some day. Best  [monitor your UPS](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4347) and umount the USB when you are on battery... The UPS will also tell you when its going to run out of power so that you can initiate a complete system shutdown.

Comment: Yes I understand that emergency mode makes sense but I think that it's an overkill to prevent the server from booting via emergency mode if only one external harddrive failed. Isn't it? If there was an optional timeout on emergency mode after which the server would try to boot normally, it would save a lot of 'deadlocks' when someone need to physically attach a keyboard and a display to the server and press a button to reboot it. It wasn't the first time it happened, very unplesant :(

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this was ever solved, but adding the "nofail" option to my /etc/fstab file is what solved this for me. Example:

```
UUID=1a1a1a1a-3b1b1-3c3c3-4d4d4-5e5e5e5e5e5e /mnt/backups ext4 defaults,nofail 0 0
```